# Detect pattern from filename, then extract 5 more character from the right

Tags: python

I have thousands of file from A directory, what I want to do are:

1. Detect any files with "ABC" in filename.
2. Once detected, extract 5 more character on the right.

Example:

```
34291.daveabc2712144.txt
eidddvabc24156.mp3
beonabcsimple.csv
```

Output:

```
abc27121
abc24156
abcsimpl
```

Thanks with Regards

Jack

Comment: What if abc is in the string multiple times?

Comment: Also, what if there are less than five trailing characters after `'abc'`?

Comment: - If multiple pattern detect within a filename (Rare case), it will pick the first detected ABC and then retrieve the next 5 characters.
- If less than five trailing characters, it will pick what ever exist even file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
abc.{5}
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

strings = ["34291.daveabc2712144.txt", "eidddvabc24156.mp3", "beonabcsimple.csv"]

rx = re.compile(r'abc.{5}')

names = [m.group(0) for string in strings for m in [rx.search(string)] if m]
print(names)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/RUIDwb/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '34291.daveabc2712144.txt'
>>> s[(start := s.index('abc')): start + 8] 
'abc27121'
```

Assumes that `'abc'` can be found and requires Python 3.8+ for walrus operator.

No need for regex for such a simple task in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using regex:

```
import re
txts = ["34291.daveabc2712144.txt",
        "eidddvabc24156.mp3",
        "beonabcsimple.csv",
        "fABCgfdge.txt"]
for i in txts:
    x = re.findall("abc.{5}", i)
    #if you need to be case insensitive you can do this
    #x = re.findall("abc.{5}", i, re.IGNORECASE)
    if x:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `glob` module. Assuming all the `abc` are lowercase:

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob('*abc*'): # For every file that has 'abc' in it
    i = file.find('abc') # Find the index of the 'abc'
    print(file[i:i+8]) # Print out the file name 5 characters from the end of 'abc', or 8 from the start
```

The beuty of this is this: `glob('*abc*')` so that we don't list *all* the files in the first place, only the ones that have `'abc'` in the name.